# How to handle exceptions thrown in Wicket custom model?

Tags: error-handling, wicket

I have a component with a custom model (extending the wicket standard Model class). My model loads the data from a database/web service when Wicket calls `getObject()`.

This lookup can fail for several reasons. I'd like to handle this error by displaying a nice message on the web page with the component. What is the best way to do that?

```
public class MyCustomModel extends Model {

    @Override
    public String getObject() {
        try {
            return Order.lookupOrderDataFromRemoteService();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Failed silently...");
            // How do I propagate this to the component/page?
        }           
        return null;
}
```

Note that the error happens *inside* the Model which is decoupled from the components.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your model could implement IComponentAssignedModel, thus being able to get hold on the owning component.

But I wonder how often are you able to reuse MyCustomModel? 
I know that some devs advocate creating standalone model implementations (often in separate packages). While there are general cases where this is useful (e.g. FeedbackMessagesModel), in my experience its easier to just create inner classes which are component specific.

Comment: +1 for teaching me about `IComponentAssignedModel`. It's just what I was thinking about when I wrote that answer. It's nice to see how Wicket always has a perfect-fit solution for almost any use cases.

Comment: We have some model classes with extra logic that get reused all over the place. They also get passed from page to page, which is not recommended for anonymous/inner classes. Also even in one single page you often can have models that should be shared between several components such as a label and a formcomponent. Or several panels that display different properties of the same object. For that use case, the IComponentAssignedModel would be appropriate.

Comment: Lots of good answers here, but this captures the gist: add a reference to the component in the model.

Answer (score 7):

Handling an exception that happens in the model's getObject() is tricky, since by this time we are usually deep in the response phase of the whole request cycle, and it is too late to change the component hierarchy. So the only place to handle the exception is very much non-local, not anywhere near your component or model, but in the `RequestCycle`.

There is a way around that though. We use a combination of a `Behavior` and an `IRequestCycleListener` to deal with this:

- `IRequestCycleListener#onException` allows you to examine any exception that was thrown during the request. If you return an `IRequestHandler` from this method, that handler will be run and rendered instead of whatever else was going on beforehand.

  We use this on its own to catch generic stuff like Hibernate's `StaleObjectException` to redirect the user to a generic "someone else modified your object" page. If you
- For more specific cases we add a `RuntimeExceptionHandler` behavior:

  ```
  public abstract class RuntimeExceptionHandler extends Behavior {
      public abstract IRequestHandler handleRuntimeException(Component component, Exception ex);
  }
  ```

  In `IRequestCycleListener` we walk through the current page's component tree to see whether any component has an instance of `RuntimeExceptionHandler`. If we find one, we call its `handleRuntimeException` method, and if it returns an `IRequestHandler` that's the one we will use. This way you can have the actual handling of the error local to your page.

  Example:

  ```
  public MyPage() {
    ...
    this.add(new RuntimeExceptionHandler() {
      @Override public IRequestHandler handleRuntimeException(Component component, Exception ex) {
        if (ex instanceof MySpecialException) {
          // just an example, you really can do anything you want here.
          // show a feedback message...
          MyPage.this.error("something went wrong"); 
          // then hide the affected component(s) so the error doesn't happen again...
          myComponentWithErrorInModel.setVisible(false); // ...
          // ...then finally just re-render this page:
          return new RenderPageRequestHandler(new PageProvider(MyPage.this));
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      }
    });
  }
  ```

  Note: This is *not* something shipped with Wicket, we rolled our own. We simply combined the `IRequestCycleListener` and `Behavior` features of Wicket to come up with this.

Comment: You had me up until 'we walk through the current page's component tree' - how is this done?

Comment: I don't know the syntax off the top of my head right now, but you can use the visit() methods on the page object. You pass it an IVisitor and it iterates over the components, passing each of them to you. You can then check the behaviors on each component to see whether you find a RuntimeExceptionHandler.

Answer (score 2):

Being the main issue here that `Model`s are by design decoupled from the component hierarchy, you could implement a component-aware `Model` that will report all errors against a specific component.

Remember to make sure it implements `Detachable` so that the related `Component` will be detached.

If the `Model` will perform an expensive operation, you might be interested in using `LoadableDetachableModel` instead (take into account that `Model.getObject()` might be called multiple times).

```
public class MyComponentAwareModel extends LoadableDetachableModel { 
    private Component comp;         
    public MyComponentAwareModel(Component comp) { 
          this.comp = comp;
    }

    protected Object load() {
        try {
            return Order.lookupOrderDataFromRemoteService();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Failed silently...");
            comp.error("This is an error message");
        }           
        return null;
    } 

    protected void onDetach(){
        comp.detach();
    }
}
```

It might also be worth to take a try at `Session.get().error())` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a FeedbackPanel to the page and call error("some description") in the catch clause.

Comment: Given that `Model`s are decoupled from the component hierarchy, how would you call `Component#error` from the `Model`? Using `Session.get().error()` maybe?

Comment: @bert: That is the problem: you don't have access to the component hierarchy inside the model

Comment: Arrgh. Sorry, missed that point, as I never call services from the models.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to simply return null in `getObject`, and add logic to the controller class to display a message if `getObject` returns null.

If you need custom messages for different fail reasons, you could add a property like `String errorMessage;` to the model which is set when catching the Exception in `getObject` - so your controller class can do something like this

```
if(model.getObject == null) {
 add(new Label("label",model.getErrorMessage()));
} else {
 /* display your model object*/
}
```