# Restoring from component rendering failures in Wicket

Tags: java, exception, wicket

Let's consider the case:

Wicket page contains  several components and  rendering of one of them fails with some common runtime exception (like NullPointerException).

The result I see by default is: the whole page fails to render.

How to recover from this error in Wicket? What should be done, not render or replace the failing component only?

Comment: One Problem that immediatly comes to my mind: Not everything that is rendered in the HTML document is also visible to the user. For example I had a few cases where I needed to construct JavaScript on the fly and build the script inside wicket because i needed access to the markup IDs that wicket generates. What if rendering such a component fails? Also if rendering a component fails you might lose style information from that component and your error message might end up somewhere else and not where the correctly rendered component would be (The wicket modal window comes to my mind)

Comment: For Clarification: The above comment was in reference to the idea of rendering an "InternalErrorComponent" component instead of the component that failed to render.

Answer (score 0):

A custom IRequestCycleListener is the solution you are looking for. Read Carl-Eric's answer here:

[How to handle exceptions thrown in Wicket custom model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12456302/how-to-handle-exceptions-thrown-in-wicket-custom-model)

Comment: This solution is too limited because it relies on the fact that I know about dangerous code points where exception can be thrown.

In real applications an exception can be raised in very unexpected places. For example I can forget to handle correctly null-values or add a component to a tree.

The best solution here could be is to have a kind of InternalErrorComponent that will be rendered instead of the failed components. 

The question is if there is a way to catch and recover from  *all* errors during component rendering, not affecting other components in the page.

Answer (score 0):

In a "classical" wicket application where pages and components are instantiated by code in constructors and initializers you probably have to add try-catch blocks manually to each and every possible constructor call. Wicket is not a managed framework, meaning there isn't a central component factory that could be decorated by such functionality. That does not mean though that you can't create such a component factory yourself.

In a CMS-like application we've been developing since 2006 all wicket components are instantiated by builders that themselves are created from xml or json documents (so the full layout and configuration of the app is externalized and the wicket components are just small building boxes that can be mixed and matched together like lego pieces) - so I know such an approach works and performs well. In our case each builder method that creates a component has a try-catch block that creates an empty Label instead if any RuntimeException happens.

Comment: If the exception is thrown from within some stack frame below Page constructor method call - this is definitely whole-page failure that will result to InternalErrorPage if not caught by developer. But there is a separate part of rendering related to repeaters that are rendered after you exit from page constructor. Would you suggest the same logic here: wrap any populateItem call to try{}catch?

Answer (score 0):

This is weird requirement, in my humble opinion.

What is the rendering of the replacement component fails too ? Add extra logic ?! Or let it fail with stack overflow error ?

What if half of the components in the page fail ? You will show half page with proper content and the other with "Oopsies" ?!

If there is an error then it should be fixed!

Comment: Every page in wicket may contain a dozen of independent components. Once Wicket has InternalErrorPage I just see no reason to have a kind of InternalErrorComponent. The same logic, but defined on per-component level.  Anyway, thanks to all for the help!